# How to host ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application on Big Rock server?

Tags: web-hosting

I don't know how to host ASP.NET MVC application on Big Rock server? I am hosting for the first time.

Configuration:

```
  ASP.NET 4.0 MVC 3.0
  MS SQL SERVER 2008
  IIS 8
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as you host ordinary ASP website. If hosting provider's web server supports ASP.Net 4.0 and MVC 4.0 websites, you really don't have to do anything on your part. Just ensure your application is using ASP.Net 4.0 Integrated application pool.